# Compactly-supported harmonic tensors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, elliptic-pde

Let $({M},g)$ be a connected and non-compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. If $L:\Gamma^{\infty}(E)\to \Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ is a linear second order elliptic operator on some smooth $\mathbb{R}$-bundle $E$ over ${M}$, is it then true that

$$Lu=0$$

for $u\in\Gamma^{\infty}_{c}(E)$ implies that $u=0$, or in other words, there are no compactly-supported smooth homogeneous solutions? I think such a result could be proven via some ``unique continuation property of elliptic system''. However, while looking in the literature, I didn't find a suitable version for this situation.

Examples of such operator $L$ I have in mind is for example the connection Laplacian $$\Delta_{C}:=g^{ij}\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}:\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}{M}^{\otimes k})\to\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}{M}^{\otimes k})$$
with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ or closely related, the Hodge-de Rham Laplacian $$\Delta_{H}:=\mathrm{d}\delta+\delta\mathrm{d}:\Omega^{k}({M})\to\Omega^{k}({M})$$
with exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$ and codifferential $\delta$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The unique continuation is valid for  generalized Laplacians. This follows from Hörmander's result in

> *Hörmander, Lars*, [**Uniqueness theorems for second order elliptic differential equations**](https://doi.org/10.1080/03605308308820262), Commun. Partial Differ. Equations 8, 21-64 (1983). [ZBL0546.35023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0546.35023) [MR686819](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=686819)

The   operators you mentioned are such generalized Laplacians. Here are a few details.

Suppose that $E$ is a metric vector bundle over the Riemann manifold $(M,g)$. Denote by $\Delta_M$ the  scalar Laplacian determined by the metric $g$. Fix a connection on $E$ compatible with the metric on $E$ and set $\Delta_E=\nabla^*\nabla: C^\infty(E)\to C^\infty(E)$.

For any $u\in C^\infty(E)$ we have

$$\Delta_M |u(x)|_E^2=2\big\langle \Delta_E u(x),u(x)\big\rangle_E-2\vert \nabla u(x)\vert_E^2.$$

A second order partial differential operator  $L$ is called a generalized  Laplacian if   its principal symbol satisfies

$$
\sigma_L(\xi)=-|\xi|_g^2\cdot \mathbf{1}_{E_x},\;\;\forall x\in M,\;\;\forall \xi\in T^*_xM. $$

Any  generalized Laplacian   $L:C^\infty(E)\to C^\infty(E)$ has the form

$$ L=\nabla^*\nabla+ T=\Delta_E+T,$$

for some  a connection $\nabla$ on $E$ compatible with the metric on $E$   and an endomorphism  $T$ of the bundle  $E$; see [Proposition 10.1.34 here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf).

If $Lu=0$, then $\Delta_E u=-Tu$ and we deduce

$$\Delta_M |u(x)|_E^2=-2\big\langle Tu(x),u(x)\big\rangle_E-2\vert \nabla u(x)\vert_E^2.$$

At this point you can invoke the above results of Hörmander for the scalar function $|u(x)|_E^2$ to obtain the unique continuation.

Comment: Looking in from the outside, it's unfortunate that (to my knowledge) there doesn't appear to be a handy reference for (strong) unique continuation results for elliptic systems. If one doesn't know this trick of reducing to a scalar equation, or if it's not obviously applicable, the best options seems to be to start climbing up and down the citation tree from [(Hile, Protter 1976)](https://doi.org/10.1080/03605307608820017) to see if the desired class of systems has been studied.

Comment: That is true.  The only bit of good news for me at least  is that in most geometric applications  the operators involved are either of Dirac type or Laplacian type and unique continuation results are available  in such cases.

Comment: Maybe this is simple but don't you need to be able to show that $|\nabla u|_E^2 \leq C |x|^{-1+\epsilon}|\nabla_M |u|^2|$ for some constants $C,\epsilon>0$ to apply Hormanders result?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu The result of Hormander requires an estimate on the absolute value of the Laplacian what you wrote only gives a one sided bound.

Comment: @RBega2  You are correct and I have deleted that embarrassing comment.  The ad-hoc approach indicated  by  Rafe Mazzeo  works.  Aronszajn method   works in this case.   Rafe Mazzeo proves a Carleman inequality for generalized Laplacians in  his paper "Unique continuation..." Amer. J. Math. 1991.  This is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

H"ormander's result works perfectly well for any second order system with real diagonal principal part. The last few answers indicate steps to prove this, but it's more direct to just look at the proof and see that all the steps just work directly for systems of this type. It's very common that the hypothesis for such unique continuation results is simply some sort of differential inequality like this, with this sort of extension to bundles being straightforward.